# AngularJS How to get random values from ng-pluralizer?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Objective:    I want $scope .pluraliser to return random values when a year is selected e.g.  1966
currently it will always pick the last value if multiple values are the same.

$scope.pluralizer = {

```
    1966 :  "Something New !",
    1966 :  "Something Different!",
    1966 :  "Something Else",
    1967 :  "Something New !",
    1967 :  "Something Different!"',
    1967 :  "Something Else",
    1968 :  "Something New !",
    1968 :  "Something Different!",
    1968 :  "Something Else"


    }


You can randomise  nested lists quite easily with ng-repeat 

http://jsfiddle.net/owenmead/fa4v8/1/
```

$scope.list = [

```
    '"1966" :  "Something New !"',
    '"1966" :  "Something Different!"',
    '"1966" :  "Something Else"',
    '"1967" :  "Something New !"',
    '"1967" :  "Something Different!"',
    '"1967" :  "Something Else"',
    '"1968" :  "Something New !"',
    '"1969" :  "Something Different!"',
    '"1970" :  "Something Else"',

]
 $scope.random = function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();

  HTML
  <p ng-repeat="i in list|orderBy:random">{{i}}</p>
```

and randomise arrays using Fisher Yates Shuffle array  algorithm

How Can I randomise the Pluralizer so it returns different/random  values when a year is selected ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `pluralizer` variable you are overwriting the values for "1966". So while you define 3 values, each one overwrites the previous one.

One way to solve this is to store the multiple values in an array like this:

```
$scope.pluralizer = {
  1966 :  ["Something New!", "Something Different!", "Something Else"],    
  1967 :  ["Something New!", "Something Different!", "Something Else"],
  1968 :  ["Something New!", "Something Different!", "Something Else"]
}
```

With this you can get the array for 1966 and then randomly select one of the array indexes. Not sure how you want to use this variable, so I won't add any code for extracting the values randomly...